# JQuery / Vanilla Javascript translation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the majority of my site in vanilla javascript and for the sake of consistency could someone please advise how I would translate the following... Thank you!

```
 $("a").click(function(){ $("p").fadeOut(3000); });
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you search? I'm sure this has been answered somewhere or can be found via Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript fade out (vanilla js example) not working for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655298/javascript-fade-out-vanilla-js-example-not-working-for-me)

Comment: For the fadeout I would probably use a CSS class w/ transition. Then just grab the element and add the class when its clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656038/3599496

View that link, it has the answer you're looking for. For the click event, view:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp